# Magento 2: How override native crontab.xml

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, cronjobs

I would like to **override some cron jobs** of native crontab.xml

for example,

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/src/Payment/etc/crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="get_amazon_capture_updates" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\GetAmazonCaptureUpdates" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="get_amazon_authorization_updates" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\GetAmazonAuthorizationUpdates" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\ProcessAmazonRefunds" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

I've created a very simple extension here

> app/code/CustomVendor/Cron/

with file

> app/code/CustomVendor/Cron/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">

        <job name="get_amazon_capture_updates" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\GetAmazonCaptureUpdates" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 1 * * 1</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="get_amazon_authorization_updates" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\GetAmazonAuthorizationUpdates" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 1 * * 1</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds" instance="Amazon\Payment\Cron\ProcessAmazonRefunds" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 1 * * 1</schedule>
        </job>

        <job name="magento_newrelicreporting_cron" instance="Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Cron" method="runCron">
            <schedule>0 2 * * 1</schedule>
        </job>

    </group>
</config>
```

I ran the **commands**:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Checked **cron_schedule** table. As I see it does not help.

[image]

What I did wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way is to add this kind of record for `core_config_data` table :

```
path : crontab/default/jobs/get_amazon_capture_updates/schedule/cron_expr
value : 0 1 * * 1
scope: default
scope_id: 0
```

You have to do this for all cronjobs you want to update. I also suggest to install module https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager which allows you to change schedule for each cron job directly from the admin panel.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just overridden a few native cron jobs which were present in the `Magento_Indexer` module.

The concept is, to override a native cron, you have to create a crontab.xml file in your custom module and use the same name of cron job in your custom module which is mentioned in the native cron job. Also add the dependency (`sequence` node )in `etc/module.xml`.

The process I followed to achieve it via custom module is given below.

Added following code to `etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amitshree_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Indexer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And added below code to `etc/crontab.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job name="indexer_reindex_all_invalid" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ReindexAllInvalid" method="execute">
            <schedule>5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_update_all_views" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview" method="execute">
            <schedule>9 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_clean_all_changelogs" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ClearChangelog" method="execute">
            <schedule>4 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Question**: How to verify it works properly?

**Answer**: Follow below steps to verify it.

- After making above changes flush your cache.
- run command `php bin/magento cron:run` from root of your project
- Connect to your database via sql command `use magento2;`
- ### run below sql queries

1. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_reindex_all_invalid';`

Output:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                    | scheduled_at        |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_reindex_all_invalid | 2020-02-26 11:05:00 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

2. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_update_all_views';`

Output:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                 | scheduled_at        |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_update_all_views | 2020-02-26 11:09:00 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

3. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_clean_all_changelogs';`

Output:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                     | scheduled_at        |
+------------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_clean_all_changelogs | 2020-02-26 11:04:00 |
+------------------------------+---------------------+
```